# What is the best way to access values in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

For example I have

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
df[df['a']==3].a = 4
```

This does not assign 4 to where 3 is

```
df[df['a']==3] = 4
```

But this works.

It confused me on how the assignment works. Appreciate if anyone can give me some references or explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do *not* want to use the second method. It returns a dataframe subslice and assigns the same value to every single row.

For example,

```
df

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  3
2  3  6

df[df['a'] == 3]

   a  b
2  3  6

df[df['a']==3] = 3

df

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  3
2  3  3
```

The first method does not work because boolean indexing returns a copy of the column (series), which you are trying to assign to, so assignment fails:

```
df[df['a'] == 3].a = 4
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:3110: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self[name] = value
```

---

So, your options are using `.loc` (access by name) or `iloc` (access by index) based indexing:

```
df.loc[df.a == 3, 'a'] = 4

df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  4
```

If you are passing a boolean mask, you cannot use `iloc`.

Comment: `df.a=np.where(df.a==3,4,df.a)` maybe also good for him knowing `numpy` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `.loc` with boolean index and column label selection:

```
df.loc[df.a == 3,'a'] = 4
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  4
```

In your method what is happening is that you are slicing your dataframe and pandas is creating a copy and that assignment is happening on the copy of the dataframe and not the original dataframe itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
In [1289]: df.loc[df['a']==3, 'a'] = 4

In [1290]: df
Out[1290]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it like this

```
df['a'] = df['a'].replace(3, 4)
```

(modified, thanks @COLDSPEED)

Answer (score 0):

you would want to do

```
df['a'].apply(lambda x: 4 if x ==3 else x)
```

which would give:

```
0    1
1    2
2    4
```

Comment: Apply is considered the filthy reject of the pandas API family.